# Question About Example In Robert C Martin's _Clean Code_

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is a question about the concept of a function doing only one thing.  It won't make sense without some relevant passages for context, so I'll quote them here.  They appear on pgs 37-38:

> To say this differently, we want to be able to read the program as though it were a set
>   of TO paragraphs, each of which is describing the current level of abstraction and referencing subsequent TO paragraphs at the next level down.
>
> *To include the setups and teardowns, we include setups, then we include the test page content, and then we include the teardowns. To include the setups, we include the suite setup if this is a suite, then we include the regular setup.*
>
> It turns out to be very difﬁcult for programmers to learn to follow this rule and write
>   functions that stay at a single level of abstraction. But learning this trick is also very
>   important. It is the key to keeping functions short and making sure they do “one thing.”
>   Making the code read like a top-down set of TO paragraphs is an effective technique for
>   keeping the abstraction level consistent.

He then gives the following example of poor code:

```
public Money calculatePay(Employee e) 
throws InvalidEmployeeType {
switch (e.type) {
  case COMMISSIONED:
    return calculateCommissionedPay(e);
  case HOURLY:
    return calculateHourlyPay(e);
  case SALARIED:
    return calculateSalariedPay(e);
  default:
    throw new InvalidEmployeeType(e.type);
}
}
```

and explains the problems with it as follows:

> There are several problems with this function. First, it’s large, and when new
>   employee types are added, it will grow. Second, it very clearly does more than one thing.
>   Third, it violates the Single Responsibility Principle7
>   (SRP) because there is more than one
>   reason for it to change. Fourth, it violates the Open Closed Principle8
>   (OCP) because it
>   must change whenever new types are added.

Now my questions.

To begin, it's clear to me how it violates the OCP, and it's clear to me that this alone makes it poor design.  However, I am trying to understand each principle, and it's not clear to me how SRP applies. Specifically, the only reason I can imagine for this method to change is the addition of new employee types.  There is only one "axis of change."  If details of the calculation needed to change, this would only affect the submethods like "calculateHourlyPay()"

Also, while in one sense it is obviously doing 3 things, those three things are all at the same level of abstraction, and can all be put into a TO paragraph no different from the example one: *TO calculate pay for an employee, we calculate commissioned pay if the employee is commissioned, hourly pay if he is hourly, etc*.  So aside from its violation of the OCP, this code seems to conform to Martin's other requirements of clean code, even though he's arguing it does not.

Can someone please explain what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What's a TO paragraph???

Comment: It's explain in the OP, it's a concept from the book

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be two reasons for calculatePay to change:

1. Changes in employee types
2. Changes in pay calculations

Two different axes of change. However, calculatePay method's responsibility is pay calculation. It should only change if there is a change in the pay calculation formula. I think this is why the author states that the method violates SRP.

In the book, the author provides a solution where he defines classes for each employee type derived from a common Employee abstract base class. He moves calculatePay method to Employee base class and defines an Employee factory class that creates appropriate employee objects given an employee type. This way each pay calculation is encapsulated in a specific employee type class and therefore not affected by changes in employee types. Also the employee factory class in this simple solution is only affected by changes in employee types. So the new solution makes SRP happy.

In the new solution, you ask an employee to calculate his/her pay which I don't like because this does not reflect the reality. You can actually argue that this too is a violation of SRP. This calculation is the responsibility of the payroll department. I like it where the model in software represents the real world domain as much as possible but we usually have to make compromises. In this case, I would say that changes in employee types are not going to happen on regular bases. In fact, they will most likely occur very rarely. So I would keep things where they make sense business domain wise such as asking payroll object to calculate employee pay. At the same time, I would have and keep an extensive suit of unit tests as one should have to ensure that when a change in employee type occurs everything continues to work as expected.

Comment: Seems same as my response ;-)

Comment: That's up to the op and the other readers. There are additional things such as the solution given in the book and my  take on it (last paragraph).

Comment: How would changes in pay calculation affect the method?  They would only affect the submethods like calculateHourlyPay(), as I said in my OP.  So I still see only one axis of change: ie, a new employee type.

Comment: Use your imagination :-) Change happens all the time and in ways you never imagined. Some examples: what if a change required you to pass some payroll policies to pay calculations or a change in rules that now allows salaried employees to receive a commission on a sale for which they made a significant contribution, etc. In the face of these and similar pay calculation changes, you may find it very hard to keep calculatePay method untouched.

Comment: If you had to start passing an argument to calculatePay(), then that requires changing the Employee abstraction as well, so the solution given in the book would not be open to that kind of modification either (see http://pastebin.ca/2030006 for book soln).  So I think using that as an example of a change of axis is cheating.  Can you give me a *specific* example, other than change in employee type, of a change that will cause the original switch statement calculatePay() method to change but which will not cause any change in solution using an abstract interface?

Comment: Why is it cheating? That's a change and affects how the pay is calculated. Using the original calculatePay method with the employee type switch statement, I may now need to pull the appropriate pay policies from a database or a web service and make them available before calling one of the pay calculation methods. Alternatively, you can allow policies to be injected but are you not going to check if policies are set in calculatePay method? Was there a change in employee type? No. There are now policies that must be taken into account when calculating pays.

Comment: Maybe I am not following you.  It seems to me the changes you are suggesting require changes to the abstraction solution as well, so that's why it's cheating.  It's only valid if Martin's solution is open to the changes but the original bad code is not.  Can you be more specific about the example you are proposing?

Comment: Apparently. I am talking about SRP and trying to show how the original calculatePay method may need to be changed even if there is no change in employee types. You said that you saw only one axis of change for that method and that was the employee type. btw I don't agree with the solution proposed in the book by moving the calculatePay method to Employee abstraction since I don't see pay calculation as being the responsibility of an employee.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I can see your point.  And I think my objection is not valid anyway, since with Martin's solution you could modify the HourlyEmployee class or whatever and stick payroll policies into that.  I think your objection to Martin's solution is pretty silly though.  I mean, if you don't like the fact that an employee is calculating pay because in real-life employees dont do that, just rename the abstract class EmployeeUtility or something that doesn't offend your sense of real-life analogy.

Comment: Hmmm... on second thought, maybe I don't see your point.  If you needed to pass some payroll policies to the calculateHourlyPay(e), you would only need to modify that method, not the calculatePay() method itself.  So I still think only a new employee type can force a change.....

Comment: Well you are entitled to your opinion. I don't see how renaming the abstract class helps here. I just don't want an hourly employee to worry about pay calculation on top of the responsibilities of an hourly employee. If you want to take pay calculation out of hourly employee and stick it into an employee utility class, that's fine and one way of doing it not what I would do. About your comment "..you would only need to modify that method, not the calculatePay method..", calculatePay calls that method (#1). #2 where are policies coming from? still think calculatePay does not need to be changed?

Comment: #1 so calculatePay calls that method, i don't see how that's releant.  #2 yes i still think calculatePay does not to be changed, no matter where the policies are coming from.  The submethods would need to be changed, and you give them some handle to the policies info, or hardcode it right into them.  I don't see how this forces a change in calculatePay. on another note, how would you do the refactoring in a way you like?

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a long shot here as I doesn't have enough context. This method might change due to TWO reasons (by the way the code also violates the basic encapsulation principle)

1. When a new employee type is added but the pay calculation strategy fits with existing strategies
2. When a new employee type is added AND and that requires a new pay calculation strategy

In both of those cases, the abstraction that need to change is the new Employee type added, not the client/user of Employee class. I mean to say that the (pay calculation should be encapsulated) calculatePay() method belongs to Employee abstraction something lime below

```
interface SalariedEmployee
{
BigDecimal calculatePay();
}

class HourlyEmployee implements SalariedEmployee
{
}

class CommissionedEmployee implements SalariedEmployee
{
}
```

Comment: hmmm.... in both cases it still requires the adding of a new employee type to trigger the need for change.  your solution is correct and fixes the violation of the OCP, but i still don't see why the SRP is being violated.

Comment: Another way of looking at SRP is "A class should change for only one reason". In my opinion this is the correct interpretation of SRP. A class can do multiple things if they are all logically related, focused on doing one logical thing and change together. I believe people are taking this literally thus creating smaller classes ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused how your comment applies to my original question.  My point was that the method could only change for one reason (a new employee type), and thus it conforms to SRP.  are you saying that the 3 types of pay calculations are not logically related, and thus not a single responsibility?  while i'd agree, i think using the logically related criterion is a slippery slope, because "logically related" will be subjective in many cases, while the "single reason for change" is less so.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to figure it out and I think I might have found something to convince you if you are not.

There are actually 2 reasons to change this method:

1. pay calculation: because you can decide for any reason that an HourlyPaidEmployee will now be paid using the monthly strategy. You are not changing the proper formula of the calculation but the way you pay this type of employee which is basically a change on the same level of abstraction.
2. change in employee types: you can add another type of employee (freelancer) or even rename the type to something else.

Post seems to be a bit old but I hope this will help other people to understand.